# Trouble understanding and creating dynamic JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, merge

I hope my code can explain itself, I am almost there, I just am stuck on the way how to merge optional data into a JSON object with multiple levels (is that even what it is?)

```
//get video list - example: video1.flv;test23.flv;Grabledable.flv
var files = j('.videos').html().split(';');
// assume first we have one video, so no need of playlist
var isplaylist = false;
// check if there are actually more than one video
if (files.length > 1) {
    isplaylist = true;
    var playlist = new Array(); // is this right? I want to add this to the video var
    for (var i in files) {
        playlist[] = {
            url: files[i],
            title: 'Video ' + i
        };
    }
};

//here's where the trouble starts
var video = {
    plugins: {
        controls: {
            playlist: isplaylist,
            //i cut out all irrelevant extra data
        }
    }, 
    clip: {

        url: files[0],
        // ONLY DO THIS IF isplayer == false;
        wmode: 'opaque',
        baseUrl: "/video/",
        autoPlay: false
    },

    // from here on this should only occur if isplayer == true;
    // following is the way I want it attached from var playlist
    playlist: [{
        url: 'video1.flv',
        title: 'Video 0'
    },
    {
        url: 'test23.flv',
        title: 'Video 1'
    },
    {
        url: 'Grabledable.flv',
        title: 'Video 2'
    }]
};
```

My target is the format listed here: http://flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/playlist.html under the section JavaScript coding.

Comment: If you really want to create JSON, you have to enclose the keys in double quotes `"`.

Comment: @Felix Kling: I am following the format that is predefined here http://flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/playlist.html under the section JavaScript coding

Comment: Ok, then you are not creating JSON but just a normal JavaScript Object.

Comment: @Felix Kling: thanks for clearing that up, I'm new to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you want something like this:

```
var video = {
  plugins: {
    controls: {
      playlist: false
    }
  },
  clip:  {
      wmode: 'opaque',
      baseUrl: "/video/",
      autoPlay: false
  }
}

// check if there are actually more than one video
if(files.length > 1){
  video.plugins.controls.playlist = true;
  var playlist = [];
  for ( var i = 0, l = files.length; i < l; i++ )
  {
     playlist.push({url: files[i], title: 'Video '+ i});
  }
  video.playlist = playlist;
}
else {
  video.clip.url = files[0];
}
```

The corresponding entries (like `video.playlist` or `video.clip.url`) are added dynamically. Never traverse arrays with the `for ( ... in ...)` construct!

Comment: looks like there might be a small typo in this: the playlist array in the for loop is not being indexed into.

Comment: Great, this actually helped me beyond this specific question.

Comment: Also, for..in is not the best way to iterate over indexes in an array: See mdc here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#section_4 It looks like he's using jquery to get the video DOM elements, so he should probably use jquery's .each() method instead: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @echo-flow: I must have edited my question while you wrote the comments... for such a simple task, I would not use `.each()`, as this implies a function call per element.

Answer (score 1):

1. don't use [for-in for arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript/3010848#3010848)
2. use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)  method to add new elements to an array (the format you used only exists in PHP)

Code:

```
// assuming you have video declared before
var video = { ... };

//get video list - example: video1.flv;test23.flv;Grabledable.flv
var files = j('.videos').html().split(';');
// assume first we have one video, so no need of playlist
var isplaylist = false;
// check if there are actually more than one video
if ( files.length > 1 ) {
    isplaylist = true;
    var playlist = new Array();
    for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
        playlist.push ({
            url: files[i],
            title: 'Video ' + i
        });
    }
};

video.playlist = playlist;
```